# transcribe mRNA code from DNA strand

Tags: python

I thought it would be easy to replace the string a into u and so on with this code

```
DNA= "atgcatgctagcagtcagcatcgatcgatcagctagctag"

   def transcribe(dna):

     dna.replace("a", "u")
     dna.replace("t", "a")
     dna.replace("g", "c")
     dna.replace("c", "g")
     return
```

it didn't change my variable at all. Can anybody help me to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `dna.replace` will yield the new string; it will not change `dna`. You would need to assign the result to something.
- Replacing `c` with `g` and then `g` with `c` does not do what you think. E.g. `atcg` -> `atgg` -> `atcc`.
- You do not return anything

The solution is to replace simultaneously:

```
import string
def transcribe(dna):
    return dna.translate(string.maketrans("atgc", "uacg"))
```

or to replace with an intermediary value:

```
def transcribe(dna):
    dna = dna.replace("a", "u")
    dna = dna.replace("t", "a")
    dna = dna.replace('g', '_')
    dna = dna.replace('c', 'g')
    dna = dna.replace('_', 'c')
    return dna
```